# pyodbc query with dates variable (get data for last week +4hours)

Tags: python, pandas, pyodbc

I am quite new on Python and even newer on SQL...
I am stuck on pyodbc query which:

1. should create dataframe with data for the last week +4.5 hours. (Example: last Monday= 07/03/2022 00:00:00, till this Monday = 14/03/2022 04:30:00.
2. main Table for query is `tblLogs`, it has `LogDateTime` column in format: **2022-03-11 20:29:53.000**
3. `tblLogs` has lots of columns, so I pass the list of columns `LogColumnForQuery` also...

At the moment, I use the code below, but it collects data between two dates only...
I was not able to figure out how to add few hours after Sunday's midnight.
code example:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnx = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=' + driver + ';SERVER=tcp:' + server + ';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + database +
                     ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)
cursor = cnx.cursor()
# creating list of columns to select
LogColumns = ['LogID', 'LogDateTime', 'EmployeeID', 'EntryPointID', 'EventType', 'DeviceID']
LogColumnForQuery = ', '.join(LogColumns)

#main query
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('SET DATEFIRST 1 SELECT ' + LogColumnForQuery +
                              '''
                                FROM tblLogs
                                WHERE LogDateTime >= DATEADD(day, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) + 6), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
                                AND LogDateTime <  DATEADD(day, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()), CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())); ;
                                '''
                              , cnx)

df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Test\Monday\LastWeekLogs_Data.csv', index=False)
```

**I am trying to introduce the following, with no progress...**

these dates and their formats are killing me ;)
please advise

as per code belo, - most likely my query is not correct and the column list is not in the correct format....

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

today = datetime.now()
lastMon = (today - timedelta(days = today.weekday(), weeks=1))
thisMon = today - timedelta(days = today.weekday())
lastMon = lastMon.replace(hour=00, minute=00, second=00, microsecond=00)
thisMon = thisMon.replace(hour=4, minute=30, second=00, microsecond=00)
lastMon = datetime.strftime(lastMon, '%d/%m/%Y %X')
thisMon = datetime.strftime(thisMon, '%d/%m/%Y %X')

cnx = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=' + driver + ';SERVER=tcp:' + server + ';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + database +
                     ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)
cursor = cnx.cursor()

# creating list of columns to select
LogColumns = ['LogID', 'LogDateTime', 'EmployeeID', 'EntryPointID', 'EventType', 'DeviceID']
LogColumnForQuery = ', '.join(LogColumns)

sql_query = pd.read_sql_query(f'SELECT {LogColumnForQuery} FROM tblLogs WHERE '
                              f'LogDateTime > ({lastMon}) AND LogDateTime < ({thisMon})'
                              , cnx)

df = pd.DataFrame(sql_query)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Test\Monday\LastWeekLogs_Data.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would import numpy and use a delta time to get you what you need

```
end_date = datetime.datetime.now()
first_date = start_date - datetime.timedelta(days = 6)

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(first_date, end_date, freq = '1D'), columns = ['Date'])
df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.day_name()
df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(lambda x : datetime.datetime.strftime(x, '%d/%m/%Y %X'))
current_monday = df['Date'].loc[df['Day'] == 'Monday'].values[0]
current_monday = datetime.datetime.strptime(current_monday, '%d/%m/%Y %X')
minutes_to_lookback = ((7 * 24 * 60) + (4 * 60) + 30)
last_monday = current_monday - datetime.timedelta(minutes = minutes_to_lookback)

current_monday = datetime.datetime.strftime(current_monday, '%d/%m/%Y %X')
last_monday = datetime.datetime.strftime(last_monday, '%d/%m/%Y %X')

cnx = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=' + driver + ';SERVER=tcp:' + server + ';PORT=1433;DATABASE=' + database +
                     ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)
cursor = cnx.cursor()

# creating list of columns to select
LogColumns = ['LogID', 'LogDateTime', 'EmployeeID', 'EntryPointID', 'EventType', 'DeviceID']
LogColumnForQuery = "'" + "', '" .join(LogColumns) + "'" 

query = f"""
SELECT 
    {LogColumnForQuery} 
FROM tblLogs 
WHERE 1=1
    and LogDateTime between {current_monday} and {last_monday}
"""

sql_query = pd.read_sql_query(query, cnx)
sql_query.to_csv(r'C:\Test\Monday\LastWeekLogs_Data.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for quite extensive code.
however it causes almost the same error:


`cur.execute(*args, **kwargs)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ' \nFROM tblLogs \nWHERE 1=1\n    and LogDateTime between 15/03/2022 19:23:55 and 08/03/2022 14:53:55\n'. (105) (SQLExecDirectW)")`


plus, date range is produced incorrectly, as it does not pick up last and current Monday

Comment: as I understand `LogColumnForQuery = "'" + ", '".join(LogColumns) + "'"` causes error.
it does not produce the list correctly

Comment: No problem, if the way you did the LogColumnForQuery variable worked for you then I would keep it that way. I didn't realized that you needed the previous Monday to the Monday before that - another 4.5 hours. Let me tweek the code and get back to you with something

Comment: I tried my code for the  list instead of yours, - no luck...
my list is spit out without quotes, - yours has some, but some missing

Comment: I've updated the code to be what you need. I saw what I did for the column_list I had forgotten to add a ' back into the join.

Comment: Thanks mate, - now column list goes correctly, but not the "date time" string... :(
`    and LogDateTime between 14/03/2022 21:10:20 and 07/03/2022 16:40:20
': ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '21'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")`
Maybe it is stored on the server not in the format I get it via initial code...

Comment: Silly me... 
I had to check the date format via notepad...
it is `2022-03-11 20:29:53.000` format, with microseconds...

Comment: So you need it to have the .000 as well or not?

Comment: I guess, so, - have no time to test today... need to go to sleep, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Using Python `datetime` and SQLAlchemy Core you can avoid string formatting/quoting and other inconveniences:

```py
import datetime

import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://scott:tiger^5HHH@mssql_199")

table_name = "tblLogs"

# set up test environment
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql(f"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {table_name}")
    conn.exec_driver_sql(
        f"CREATE TABLE {table_name} (id int primary key, LogDateTime datetime2)"
    )

# test
tbl_logs = sa.Table(table_name, sa.MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

start_of_today = datetime.datetime.combine(
    datetime.date.today(), datetime.datetime.min.time()
)
start_of_last_monday = start_of_today - datetime.timedelta(
    days=start_of_today.weekday()
)  # (same as today if today is a Monday)
start_time = start_of_last_monday - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
end_time = start_of_last_monday + datetime.timedelta(hours=4.5)

qry = sa.select(tbl_logs).where(
    tbl_logs.c.LogDateTime.between(start_time, end_time)
)

engine.echo = True
df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, engine)
""" SQL rendered:
SELECT [tblLogs].id, [tblLogs].[LogDateTime] 
FROM [tblLogs] 
WHERE [tblLogs].[LogDateTime] BETWEEN ? AND ?

[generated in 0.00080s] (datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 14, 4, 30))
"""
```

Comment: :( error on the `df = pd.read_sql_query(qry, engine)`
milliseconds probably needed...
***(pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'tblLogs', database 'master', schema 'dbo'. (229) (SQLExecDirectW)")
[SQL: SELECT [tblLogs].id, [tblLogs].[LogDateTime] 
FROM [tblLogs] 
WHERE [tblLogs].[LogDateTime] BETWEEN ? AND ?]
[parameters: (datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 14, 4, 30))]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
***

Comment: You are hitting the [master] database. You'll need to adjust your connection settings to specify your own database. (The URL above uses an ODBC DSN named `mssql_199` that contains the `Driver=`, `Server=`, `Database=`, etc.. Details on connection URLs [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc).)

Comment: thanks, - close! :)

***2022-03-16 14:23:04,580 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT [tblLogs].id, [tblLogs].[LogDateTime] 
FROM [tblLogs] 
WHERE [tblLogs].[LogDateTime] BETWEEN ? AND ?
2022-03-16 14:23:04,580 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00058s] (datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 7, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 14, 4, 30))

but the result df is empty... no data received and no error

Comment: If you are using the example above, including the DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE statements, then the table is created but it is empty. You could `conn.exec_driver_sql(f"INSERT INTO {table_name} (id, LogDateTime) VALUES (1, '2022-03-10 09:08:07')")` immediately after the CREATE TABLE to have something to return.

Comment: I guess, my table gets deleted after my initial query...

Comment: Why dropping is needed initially?

Comment: Example code often drops and re-creates the test tables so the example is repeatable. Real code would obviously not drop the table; it would just assume that it already exists.

Comment: Sorry do bother again, - as per your code, - how to close the connection completely?
it is kinda confusing in sqlalchemy. P.S. Just in case, I will also run 4 more queries in the same DataBase, - quering different tables.
P.P.S. initial query wroks fine and time range is selected as needed, - Thanks Again!

Comment: The above code does not open any connections explicitly. Things that consume `engine` (i.e., `autoload_with` and `.read_sql_query()`) will open connections as needed, and should either close them or return them to the connection pool.